# Autorepeat held button on webpage on Android

Tags: javascript, android

I have a page that autorepeats a button when held. On `mousedown` it begins an interval and on `mouseup` it stops. It works flawlessly on my computer. However, it doesn't do anything in Android. Is there something you have to set for Android to allow repeating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you need `touchstart` and `touchend` events instead. Here is some documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent)